# Different console.log()s in stackoverflow snippet vs. browser console - why?

Tags: javascript, prototype

```js
const func = function() {
  this.name = 'mon'
}
let f1 = new func
let f2 = Object.create(f1) 
let f3 = Object.create(f2) // The following comments are what the browser console logs:
console.log(f1.__proto__) // {constructor: f}
console.log(f2.__proto__) // func {name: "mon"}
console.log(f3.__proto__) // func {}   (here's where this snippet logs func {"name": "mon"})
```

Also, is an object's 'type' in JS determined by its 'nearest' constructor?
(i.e. func being the type the browser logs for `f1` & `f2` )?

Comment: Well, a stack snippet simulates basic console output, mostly by calling JSON.stringify() I guess. It would be a huge amount of work to copy the browser console exactly (which is not exactly the same between for instance Firefox and Chrome anyway), and it's not necessary to do that, and partly impossible anyway. The question is rather, why *would you* expect them to be exactly the same, which makes no sense?

Comment: My take is: This stackoverflow snippet logs the wrong .__proto__ object. And there's only one correct .__proto__ object for this code in JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that the Stack Snippet console (whose code can be found [here](https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1:formatted)) iterates over properties using `for..in`. This **will include** enumerable properties anywhere on the prototype chain. This is (part of) how the snippet console figures out properties to log:

```
    function n(e) {
        var n = [];
        for (var o in e)
            n.push(o);
        return n
    }
```

For example:

```js
const proto = { prop: 'val' };
const obj = Object.create(proto);
console.log(obj); // browser console shows `Object`, but no `prop` property
```

In contrast, in the browser console, only properties directly on a logged object will be displayed. In order to access the internal prototype of the logged object (and see possible properties on the prototype), you'll have to click on the `__proto__` property to expand it.

[image]

Because the `constructor` property of a `someFunction.prototype` is *not* enumerable, it won't be iterated over via `for..in`, so it's seen in the *browser* console, but not in the snippet console.

```js
const func = function() {
  this.name = 'mon'
}
console.log(func.prototype.hasOwnProperty('constructor'));
for (const prop in func.prototype) {
  console.log(prop); // Nothing is logged
}
```

> Also, is an object's 'type' in JS determined by its 'nearest' constructor? (i.e. func being the type the browser logs for f1 & f2 )?

Every object has *exactly one* internal prototype. In your snippet, the internal prototype of `f3` is `f2`, the internal prototype of `f2` is `f1`, and the internal prototype of `f1` is `func.prototype`. Something in a prototype chain *may* also have a `constructor` property (`func.prototype.constructor === func`), but the fact that such a property exists doesn't really have an effect on the internal prototype chain, it's just an convenient method to link a `.prototype` object to its associated `function`.

Comment: Nice catch. So S.O. snippets only console.log enumerable properties. In testing this, adding an enumerable property to `f3`'s `.__proto` (which is `f2`) such as `f2.name = 'mon2'` has the snippet logging the correct .__proto__ object.

Comment: In your answer to my second Q, it seems you're interpreting my use of 'type' as equivalent to 'prototype'. I'm wondering a) is the browser console.logging `func` a reference to `f1 & f2`'s type? b) if so, is this type determined by the nearest constructor?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean, the name that comes just after the `>` in the browser console. Yeah, it looks like the browser might be finding the closest ancestor object in the prototype chain which has a `.constructor` property, and outputs the name of that function - similar to the [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator.

Comment: Well put. It seems that canonically in JS, an object's nearest constructor or its 'closest ancestor object in the prototype chain which has a .constructor property' = its 'type'?

Comment: I'm not sure if the "type" you're referring to has any official meaning in JS - I think it may just be something that browsers use to allow for easier debugging.

Comment: If `typeof` returns the nearest built in type, and instanceOf returns the nearest custom type: it seems 'type' can be swapped with `constructor` and still be valid.

Comment: Not exactly, `typeof` will either return a primitive type, `object`, or `function`, nothing else. `instanceof` requires *two* operators: the object to check, and the function / constructor to compare against. (`f3 instanceof func` -> `true`)